# Creating instant invite using discord.py rewrite, can't seem to do so without errors

Tags: python, python-3.7, discord.py

I am using python to make my bot generate an instant invite.
However I have trouble finding and creating the instant invite.
Here is my code:

```py
from progress.bar import Bar # Only to show a loading bar, all imports are successful.
print("Loading...")
imports = [
    'import os',
    'import sys',
    'import asyncio',
    'import discord',
    'import random',
    'import functools',
    'import time as tm',
    'from discord.ext import commands',
    'from discord.ext.commands import when_mentioned'

]

bar = Bar('', max=len(imports))
for i in range(0, len(imports)):
    exec(str(imports[i]))
    bar.next()
bar.finish()

BOT_PREFIX = "!"
BOT_TOKEN = 'token'
OWNER_ID = int("owner's user id for support")

class Stuff(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def create_invite(self, ctx):
        """- Create instant invite"""
        link = await discord.abc.GuildChannel.create_invite(self, max_age='300')
        await ctx.send("Here is an instant invite to your server: "+link)
```

When the command is run in discord, I get this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Stuff' object has no attribute '_state'

How can I properly generate an instant invite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [discord.TextChannel.create_invite()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_invite)

Like so,

```
@commands.command()
async def create_invite(self, ctx):
    """Create instant invite"""
    link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 300)
    await ctx.send("Here is an instant invite to your server: " + link)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example; format it as you like:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def invite(ctx):
  #Creating an invite link
  link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(xkcd=True, max_age = 0, max_uses = 0)
  #max_age = 0 The invite link will never exipre.
  #max_uses = 0 Infinite users can join throught the link.
  #-----------------------------------------------------#

  #-------Embed Time-----#
  em = discord.Embed(title=f"Join The {ctx.guild.name} Discord Server Now!", url=link, description=f"**{ctx.guild.member_count} Members** [**JOIN**]({link})\n\n**Invite link for {ctx.channel.mention} is created.**\nNumber of uses: **Infinite**\nLink Expiry Time: **Never**", color=0x303037)
  
  #Embed Footer
  em.set_footer(text=f"Made by </iFreakuYT>2.0#0908")
  
  #Embed Thumbnail Image
  em.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
  
  #Embed Author
  em.set_author(name="INSTANT SERVER INVITE")
  #-----------------------------------------#
  await ctx.send(f"> {link}", embed=em)
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

[image]